# How to get IEnumerable<T> from List<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a List and I need an IEnumerable, however List.GetEnumerator() returns List.Enumerator ...

Is there a simple way of getting (casting to?) an IEnumerator? (currently I have solved this with a loop, however I feel casting the enumerator would be a far better solution)...

Comment: `List<T>` already implements `IEnumerable<T>` so what are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean `IEnumerator<T>`?

Comment: Possibly related, though not too likely: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/07/27/iterate-damn-you.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `List<T>` is already an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Don't forget to have `using System.Linq` at the top of your file to be able to use `List<T>` as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Lukas Cenovsky: You are misguided, you only need that for the extension methods.

Comment: You're right. My point is that when I need `IEnumerable<T>`, I mostly need it because of its extension methods and I sometimes forget to include `using System.Linq`.

Comment: But that `IEnumerable` can be casted back to a `List`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you will find that a generic List implements IEnumerable, so you don't need to do anything.

What situation are you trying to use this in?

Answer (score 3):

It'll implicitly convert, so `IEnumerable<MyType> foo = myList;`

Comment: No casting happens, as it is/implements IEnumerable<T>, not castable to.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you don't need to cast it:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetIEnumerable()
{
    List<T> yourListOfT = GetList();
    return yourListOfT;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A List implements IEnumerable so just use your List.